# Find a basis for this subspace from matrices whose rank is only 1

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $W$ be the vector space over $\mathbb R$ defined by

$$ W= \begin{Bmatrix}
    \left( \begin{matrix}
  x-y&2x+y+3z\\
  -14x-7y-21z&-3x+3y
    \end{matrix} \right) | x,y,z\in \mathbb R \end{Bmatrix}
$$

Find a basis for this subspace of $\mathbb R^{2x2}$ from matrices whose rank is only 1

My way:

$$x
    \left( \begin{matrix}
  1&2\\
  -14&-3
    \end{matrix} \right)
+y
    \left( \begin{matrix}
  -1&1\\
  -7&3
    \end{matrix} \right)
+z
    \left( \begin{matrix}
  0&3\\
  -21&0
    \end{matrix} \right)
$$

Now: 
$$
    \left( \begin{matrix}
  1&2&-14&-3\\
  -1&1&-7&3\\
  0&3&-21&0\\
    \end{matrix} \right) \to
\left( \begin{matrix}
  1&2&-14&-3\\
  0&3&-21&0\\
  0&0&0&0\\
    \end{matrix} \right)
$$

So the basis I have found is:

$$\begin{Bmatrix}
    \left( \begin{matrix}
  1&2\\
  -14&-3
    \end{matrix} \right)
,
    \left( \begin{matrix}
  0&3\\
  -21&0
    \end{matrix} \right)\end{Bmatrix}
$$

But their rank is 2 and not 1 and I don't know how to continue from here.

Comment: Subtle hint: rank-1 matrix could be written as $\begin{pmatrix} a_1b_1 & a_2b_1 \\ a_1b_2 & a_2b_2 \end{pmatrix}$ (see https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1545118/113703).

Comment: OK but which 2 vectors I need to multiply?

Comment: Then not so subtle, try substituting $u = x - y, v = 2x + y + 3z$ in a matrix from $W$, and…

Comment: Then it's: $$ \begin{Bmatrix}
   u \left(  \begin{matrix}
  1&0\\
  0&3
    \end{matrix} \right) + v  \left( \begin{matrix}
  0&1\\
  -7&0
    \end{matrix} \right) \end{Bmatrix}
$$  The rank is still 2, What do I miss?

Comment: To early to expand yet—now find precisely when its rows (or columns) are linearly dependent, in terms of $u$ and $v$.