# Zero Determinant Rank 1 (2x2) matrix being expressed as an outer product of two commuting vectors (spinors)

Tags: matrices, determinant

If a 2x2 matrix has a zero determinant, why can we express it as an (outer) product of two vectors? I'm working on the spinor-helicity formalism, and am curious as to the rigorous mathematical proof behind this. Any direction to literature would be very useful!

Thank you!

EDIT: See page 10 of https://arxiv.org/pdf/1308.1697.pdf for the kind of thing I'm interested in.

Comment: Any rank $1$ matrix can be expressed as an outer product of two non-null vectors. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1545118/a-rank-one-matrix-is-the-product-of-two-vectors/1545147) for example.

Comment: @StubbornAtom thank you for the link. Would you by chance know of any linear algebra textbooks which might have a rigorous proof of this? That link is along the lines that I'm thinking. Why does zero determinant mean that it is then rank 1?

Comment: Check the several linked posts to that question; the arguments are rigorous. I guess there are standard texts that have this result as an exercise even if it is not worked out. And zero determinant of an $n\times n$ matrix means the rank is less than $n$, which in your case means the rank is $0$ (for null matrix only) or $1$.

Comment: @StubbornAtom that last line was what I needed. Thank you very much! If you put that as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @StubbornAtom's response, I found the answer that I was needing. Specifically relating to my project;

Since a zero determinant of any $n$ x $n$ matrix implies that the rank must be less than $n$, the rank for a 2x2 matrix must be 0 (null matrix) or 1. As a standard exercise in linear algebra, we can show that any rank-1 matrix may be written as the outer product of two vectors, a well-documented result in textbooks.