# Similar matrix $B$ to a matrix $A$ with rank of $1$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank

I don't know if it suppose to be an easy or a hard question but here it is:

Let $A$ a $n\times n$ matrix such that $\operatorname{rank}(A)$ =1

$\mathbf{1.}$ Proof that there exists a matrix $B$ similar to $A$ when the first $n-1$ columns of $B$ are $0$.

$\mathbf{2.}$ Proof that there exists a matrix $C$ similar to $A$ when all the rows of $C$, except the first one, are $0$.

Comment: such that rank(A)=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think of rank $1$ matrix as $A=uv^T$.
See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1545118/a-rank-one-matrix-is-the-product-of-two-vectors.) for the explanation.

Then it is possible to choose (via rotation what means that transformation matrix is orthogonal)  coordinate frame where one of the vectors would have coordinates,  $a,0,0,\dots,0$, let it be $v_r=Rv$.

The second vector $u_r$ can have any coordinates in this frame and it is transformed   $u_r=Ru$.

Obviously  matrix equal to $u_rv_r^T=Ru (Rv )^T=R(uv^T)R^T$ is similar to $uv^T$.

Now calculate  $u_rv_r^T$, 
you should obtain matrix with only one-non zero column.

For the second case change vector with one non-zero coordinate.

Comment: Of course since rotation preserves vector length we need  $\Vert v \Vert=\pm a$