# What does "rank one" in "rank one constraint system" mean?

Tags: matrices, terminology, cryptography, constraints, rank-1-matrices

Although rank one constraint system (r1cs) is heavily used in [zero-knowledge proofs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-knowledge_proof), I didn't find anywhere details on where the rank comes from.

Comment: See [this post](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/67857/what-is-a-rank-1-constraint-system)

Comment: I've read that post before,it's not clearly answered IMHO. It didn't explain why something like `A*B+C = 0` is a rank one constraint.

Comment: [A rank-one matrix is the product of two vectors](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1545118/a-rank-one-matrix-is-the-product-of-two-vectors).

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA can you be more specific about how it relates with `A*B+C = 0` ?

Comment: It's even not clear which matrix it's referring to.